# Programmatically creating a hyperlink to a worksheet

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I have been working on this for a while, I don't really know how to use vba, and I've been looking for a solution on the web for a while without success. Here is what I want to do:

I have a macro that will copy a worksheet (named "PartSheet") and put it at the end of the list of worksheets, so if I keep pressing the macro it will create pages as follow:

PartSheet (2), PartSheet (3) for the tab name and so on.

Now I am trying to add in a hyperlink into this macro so that each time I create a new copy
it will also create a hyperlink to the first worksheet (named "Summary")

Here is the code I have written:

```
Sub Test2()
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Name = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        " 'Name' !A1 ", TextToDisplay:="Link"
End Sub
```

When I run the macro, it will create the hyperlink, but it will be a invalid reference.

Comment: Sorry I think i was not clear enough. 
I am trying to add the Hyperlink on the "Summary Page" that will link to the new Copy Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with the following. Make sure you call it immediately after you make a fresh copy of your PartSheet.

```
Sub AddHyperlink()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim linkedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim linkRange As Range

    'set variable to the sheet the hyperlink will link to
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

    ' specify the range on the summary sheet to link to
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A1")

    ' set variable to sheet that will have the hyperlink
    Set linkedSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

    ' specify where on that sheet we'll create the hyperlink
    Set linkRange = linkedSheet.Range("B4")

    ' create the hypperlink on the copied sheet pointing
    ' back to the summary sheet
    linkedSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=linkRange, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & targetSheet.Name & "'!" & targetRange.Address, _
        TextToDisplay:="Go To " & targetSheet.Name

End Sub
```

**Bug-avoiding tips:**

1. Always avoid selecting or activating anything when writing Excel VBA code.
2. Always require variable declaration (in the VBE, Tools --> Options, check the box next to **Require Variable Declaration**.

Comment: Hello @Head of Catering, I have tried your code, it works fine, but it is not the reverse of what I was looking for, my apology on not explaining the situation well enough.

The code you provide will successfully create the hyperlink on the new copy page which will link back to Summary page.

But what i am looking for is the hyperlink on the Summary Page that will link to the new Copy Page. 

Still, thank you very much for your help, appreciate it, by the way, I try to change the code around, but it would not work.

Comment: I see. I edited the code to link from the Summary sheet to the new copy of PartSheet. Try again and let me know if it works. Just so you know, there were two things I changed. 1) switch the sheets referred to in the linked and target sheet, and 2) added tick marks on either side of the sheet name when setting the hyperlink

Comment: OMG, Thank you so much, finally this is working, I was looking at the reference after creating the hyperlink and yes it was missing ' ' , so that's what the & & will do. Finally got it. Thank you so much for your help . Really Appreciate it !!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because of how "SubAddress" is setup. Change it to this:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim Name As String

    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Name = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:=Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Link"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Ripster , I have tried the code, it is still not working, maybe the logic of the code was wrong to begin with ? Anyways, thank you very much for your help, i still trying it out.